# How to change the position of labels, line edits, etc relative to the window size?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI app. All the windows in the app contain line edits, buttons, etc. I want the position of those to change relative to the window size, while the application is in use. The position of those should change if the user maximizes or alters the window size.

The code is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1125, 969)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 330, 361, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 510, 75, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1125, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Window"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", " Manager"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lets Start!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(main_window)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use the designer and layouts together with spacers.

Comment: How do you want your window to look with different sizes?

Comment: @eyllanesc For example, I have given the initial position of the label (approx in the middle of the window). So, while the user changes the window size, I want the position of the label to automatically get adjusted to the center.

Comment: @M.Denis and the button?

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah the button as well. I guess the solution for labels will fit for buttons.

Comment: @M.Denis I do not understand, do you want the button to be on top of the QLabel ?, I point out that for what you point out there is no general solution, and the solution depends on the specific requirements, the solution will be a combination of layouts, sizePolicy, spacers, etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc I thought there will be a solution for relative position adjustment. I want the button to be right below the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Qt Designer I will offer a solution using that tool, for this you can use the following scheme:

```
QMainWindow
└── QHBoxLayout
    ├── QSpacerItem
    ├── QVBoxLayout
    │   ├── QSpacerItem
    │   ├── QLabel
    │   ├── QPushButton
    │   └── QSpacerItem
    └── QSpacerItem
```

Getting the following .ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>424</width>
    <height>179</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>129</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>128</width>
          <height>13</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="font">
         <font>
          <pointsize>24</pointsize>
          <weight>75</weight>
          <bold>true</bold>
         </font>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Manager</string>
        </property>
        <property name="alignment">
         <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Lets Start!</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>128</width>
          <height>13</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>128</width>
        <height>20</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>424</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image]

and then convert it to .py with pyuic.